# Specific query regarding terminology used in relation to kernel function and support vector machines

Tags: mapping, kernel, machine-learning, svm

I am currently reading the book "An Introduction to Support Vector Machines and Other Kernel Based Methods" by Nello Cristianini and I am unable to wrap my head around the concept of dual representation of linear learning machines that he discusses in chapter 2 and later also in chapter 3 in section 3.2, "The Implicit Mapping Into Feature Space", I am unaware of whether this dual representation is a general concept or whether it is a naming convention specific to this book. So that is why I am specifically citing the book and the section if anyone has already read it. If it is a general concept however I would appreciate if anyone could clarify what dual representation of a linear learning machine means and what the advantages of this dual representation are?

I hope this is not too vague a question, but unfortunately I do not have the background or the understanding of these concepts to expound further on my query.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is a general concept, it is not specific to the book.

The main benefit of the dual problem is that the data points only appear inside dot products. The dot product of every pair of data points is generally represented in a kernel matrix. If you use different type of kernels you get different types of classifiers (dot: linear, rbf,: rbf network, etc). This is called the kernel trick (or like the books you're reading appears to call it implicit mapping into feature space), one of the most important breakthroughs in machine learning in the past decade.

Not everything can be a kernel though. The kernel matrix needs to be positive semi definite. There is a great article on the [kernel trick](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel_trick) on Wikipedia. Additionally not only L2 regularized binary classifiers (SVMs) can be kernelized there are kernel perceptrons, kernel PCA, kernel everything.

Comment: I feel like I lack the mathematical background to grasp some concepts in machine learning. Would you be able to suggest a book for learning concepts like vector spaces, matrices, kernels and stuff like that. I know there might not be one book that covers all these concepts but if you know of any resource that would help me better understand the math discussed in most machine learning books and technical papers please do let me know.

Comment: Chris Bishop's book is a great point of reference: http://www.amazon.com/Pattern-Recognition-Learning-Information-Statistics/dp/0387310738


Also, you may want to examine Andrew Moore's lectures and tutorials http://www.autonlab.org/tutorials/

Oh, check out Strang's excellent lectures on linear algebra http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/mathematics/18-06-linear-algebra-spring-2010/